# How to catch/handle backend exceptions in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to learn AngularJS by building a small webapp with Spring MVC-Spring Security-AngularJS. My UserDetailsService throws a UserNotFoundException while logging in. But i don't know how to handle exceptions in Angular. I have tried to google but could not find simple, complete examples about exception handling.

This is a part of my authentication angular module:

```
                $http.get('user', {
                    headers : headers
                }).success(function(data) {
                    if (data.name) {
                        auth.authenticated = true;
                    } else {
                        auth.authenticated = false;
                    }
                    callback && callback(auth.authenticated);
                    $location.path(auth.path==auth.loginPath ? auth.homePath : auth.path);
                }).error(function() {
                    auth.authenticated = false;
                    callback && callback(false);
                });
```

How can i reach and catch this specific UserNotFoundException inside the error callback function?

Answer (score 2):

What i suggest is to create `@ExceptionHandler` in your controller and in your `UserNotFoundException` add two more fields (`errorMessage` and `errorCode`) for example. then in your angular callback you can check which is the `errorCode` number.

Good articles:

- http://java.dzone.com/articles/exception-handling-spring-rest
- http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exceptionhandler-example/

For advanced error handling I recommend this behaviour : https://github.com/jirutka/spring-rest-exception-handler

Here is a sample fiddle with your case: http://jsfiddle.net/bkUEu/1044/

Comment: I will look at it when i am at home.. looks very promising. Thank you!

Comment: no problem, if you want additional help i'm here. feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 0):

In your application angularjs try to use this

```
$http.get('user', {
                    headers : headers
                }).then(function(data) {
                    if (data.name) {
                        auth.authenticated = true;
                    } else {
                        auth.authenticated = false;
                    }
                    callback && callback(auth.authenticated);
                    $location.path(auth.path==auth.loginPath ? auth.homePath : auth.path);
                }).catch(function() {
                    auth.authenticated = false;
                    callback && callback(false);
                });
```

Use then and catch function instead of success and error.